# Varnish died by unknown reason for me

Tags: varnish

tonight I found something strange in the logs. After all, varnish stop to accept connections. After I restart it manually, it start to operation normally. Could somebody clear to me what happens? Thank you!

```
Linux,2.6.32-5-amd64,x86_64,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit
varnish-3.0.4 revision 9f83e8f

Sep 18 03:04:49 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (12939) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Sep 18 03:04:54 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (12939) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Sep 18 03:04:54 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (12939) not responding to CLI, killing it.
Sep 18 03:04:54 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (12939) died signal=3
Sep 18 03:04:54 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child cleanup complete
Sep 18 03:04:54 m32 varnishd[31985]: child (19269) Started
Sep 18 03:05:04 m32 varnishd[31985]: Pushing vcls failed:#012CLI communication error (hdr)
Sep 18 03:05:04 m32 varnishd[31985]: Stopping Child
Sep 18 03:05:04 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (19269) said Child starts
Sep 18 03:05:12 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (19269) said Child dies
Sep 18 03:05:12 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child (19269) died status=1
Sep 18 03:05:12 m32 varnishd[31985]: Child cleanup complete
```

Answer (score 0):

The status codes in this log are SIGHUP and SIGQUIT. These signals are often seen in relation with log file rotation.

Varnish itself doesn't write any log files, so this isn't necessary.

My best guess would be that you have a log rotating cronjob that kills the wrong process.

Comment: I've a similar problem. Can you please look at this question on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/575576/varnish-stops-listening-on-port-80-after-few-hours I've added logs in the question.